# Print without quotes in Java using Scanner

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java.

I used following code to get input from user

```
 Class Test
 {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
         Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
         String s=in.nextLine();
         System.out.println(s);
         in.close();
    }
 }
```

When user enters:

```
"HI"
```

I would like to print as:

```
HI
```

(without double quotes)
Please Help...

Comment: Hint: `replaceAll` method.

Comment: Your ``s`` object has methods...

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Hint: don't suggest using Regex when not necessary. `replace` is more than fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `String x = s.replaceAll("\"", "");` to remove double quotes.

Comment: `String.replace` might be better than `replaceAll` as its first argument is not considered as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a solution with `String.replace*` you will be replacing all double quotes, even if they are not the first and last characters.

If you want to make sure to only remove the leading and trailing double quotes, you can make sure they are there and then remove them:

```
if (original.startsWith("\"") && original.endsWith("\"")) {

    String newString = original.substring(1, original.length() - 1);
}
```